# Differentiate two devices with same IP using siwtches

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, switch

[image: System structure]

I have system like above.

From Client-2, I need to send different packets to VM1-Server and VM3-Server using TCP.

The problem is that both Servers have the same IP and I can't change them. It is because the programs use predefined IP and I don't have the access to its source code.

And then in Client-2, using TCP, I can't choose which `10.10.10.1` to send to because it only specifies the IP and Port it connects to.

How can I choose which Server I want to send to in Client-2?

Comment: Its complicated - you are trying to do something that is very broken.    What OS are the VN;s  using?  I might be inclined to add some NAT on each VM so I could leave the program as is, but have the OS translate it into a unique address.

Comment: While you can put those two same-addressed networks into different VLANs and they will perfeclty coexist, it is *impossible* to have such an easy connection with the external client (and to each other). It'll have to live in one of those VLANs too. Using NAT, you may allow it access the other network, but it will do this using *some other* address. Think that both those networks are like "LAN behind home router" and the external host is "Internet" and so you'll need some "home routers" to access Internet and make "port forwarding rules" to access in reverse.

Comment: Make your own virtual machines and use Hyper-V External Networking to assign IP addresses as you need.